# Phpmyadmin does not work in installation ASP:NET CORE in apache centos 7

Tags: mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin, centos7

I have successfully installed ASP.NEt in a centos 7
with this tutorial

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=dotnet20

The ASP.NET application starts without problems
including mysql but phpmyadmin does not work.

It shows me the following message in the browser

[image]

I tried the same thing running the dotnet application and leaving
execute it but it is not solved.

Any suggestions ?.

Comment: Look at your error logs to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Hello @GregKlaus`[proxy_http:error] [pid 6249] [client 181.176.85.232:42466] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Sun Apr 15 01:01:15.185380 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 6265] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sun Apr 15 01:01:15.185426 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 6265] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
[Sun Apr 15 01:01:15.185454 2018] [proxy_http:error] [pid 6265] [client 181.176.85.232:32693] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: `

Comment: PHP admin is for PHP, not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ASP.NET Core on Kestrel server hooks to port 5000,

https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639

Follow the thread to run Kestrel on another port, and then its conflict with phpmyadmin should go away.